# Function pointer as parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

Hi I've been looking over stackoverflow and I'm really struggling with function pointers as parameters.

I have the structure:

```
 struct Node {
     struct Node *next;
     short len;
     char data[6];
 };
```

and the functions:

```
 void selectionsort(int (*compareData)(struct Node *, struct Node *), void (*swapData)(struct Node *, struct Node *), int n);

 compare(struct Node *a, struct Node *b);
 swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b);
```

selection sort serves only to call compare and swap:

```
 void selectionsort(int compare(struct Node *a, struct Node *b), void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b), int n){
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
         compare(a, b);
         swap(a, b);
     }
 }
```

(the contents above may be incorrect, I have yet to get to fooling around with the actual selectionsort function really).

The problem arises when I call selectionsort in main.  I was under the impression this would work:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
     int n;
     struct Node *list = NULL;
     for (n = 1; n < argc; n++)
         list = prepend(list, argv[n]); //separate function not given here.
     int (*compareData)(struct Node *, struct Node *) = compare; //not sure I needed to redeclare this
     void (*swapData)(struct Node *, struct Node *) = swap;
     selectionsort(compareData(list, list->next), swapData(list, list->next), argc);

     //other stuff
     return 0;
 }
```

Note: the function prepend contains the malloc for the struct, so that's been dealt with.

The problem I'm having is no matter how I play around with my function declarations etc, I always get the following error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'selectionsort' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
note: expected 'int (*)(struct Node *, struct Node *)' but argument is of type 'int'.
```

Any help explaining why I'm getting this error message and how to fix it would be immensely appreciated.

I understand that the function is expecting a function pointer but I assumed my code above would allow for `compare`to be called.  Any input would be greatly appreciated, also this is for an assignment (so please help me avoid cheating) and the parameters `int(*compareData)(struct Node *, struct Node *) void (*swapData)(struct Node *, struct Node *)` were given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `selectionsort` you are actually *calling* those function pointers, causing you to pass the *result* of those calls to `selectionsort`. They are normal variables, and should be passed to `selectionsort` like any other variable argument.

However, you don't actually need the variables, you can just pass the functions directly:

```
selectionsort(&compare, &swap, argc);
```

Note that the address-of operator is not strictly needed, but I prefer to use them to explicitly tell the reader that we are passing *pointers* to those functions.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
selectionsort(compareData(list, list->next), swapData(list, list->next), argc);
```

you are passing the result of calling the function `compareData`. This is wrong.

The same holds for `swapData`.

Just pass the function itself (resp. a pointer to it):

```
selectionsort(compareData, swapData, argc);
```